# If statement ignoring equality

Tags: excel, vba

**Scenario:** I have a Function that compares the data in 2 different arrays and writes a corresponding value to a worksheet.

**Array1:**

```
+-------+----------------+-----------------+
| Name1 | Current Level1 | Previous Level1 |
+-------+----------------+-----------------+
| ID1   | b              | c               |
+-------+----------------+-----------------+
| ID2   | f*             | g               |
+-------+----------------+-----------------+
| ID3   |                |                 |
+-------+----------------+-----------------+
| ID4   | e              | e               |
+-------+----------------+-----------------+
```

**Array2:**

```
+----+--------------+
| ID | Corresponder |
+----+--------------+
| a  | 1            |
+----+--------------+
| b  | 2            |
+----+--------------+
| c  | 3            |
+----+--------------+
| d  | 4            |
+----+--------------+
| e  | 5            |
+----+--------------+
| f* | 6            |
+----+--------------+
| g  | 7            |
+----+--------------+
| h  | 8            |
+----+--------------+
| i  | 9            |
+----+--------------+
```

**Scenario:** I am running a loop that reads the letters in the first array, find a corresponding value in the second array (like a Vlookup) and writes an array exactly like the first, but instead with the corresponding numbers).

output:

```
+-------+----------------+-----------------+
| Name1 | Current Level1 | Previous Level1 |
+-------+----------------+-----------------+
| ID1   | 2              | 3               |
+-------+----------------+-----------------+
| ID2   | 6              | 7               |
+-------+----------------+-----------------+
| ID3   |                |                 |
+-------+----------------+-----------------+
| ID4   | 5              | 5               |
+-------+----------------+-----------------+
```

**Issue:** I am running this code, but for some of the values , even though the comparison is positive, the loop still jumps the inner commands.

**Code:**

```
Function match_up_values(cleanoutputArray As Variant, matchArray As Variant, targetColumn As Integer, matchColumn As Integer)

    For loopvar1 = 2 To UBound(cleanoutputArray, 1)
        For loopvar2 = 2 To UBound(matchArray, 1)
            If CStr(cleanoutputArray(loopvar1, targetColumn + 1)) = CStr(matchArray(loopvar2, ratingsColumn)) And CStr(cleanoutputArray(loopvar1, targetColumn + 1)) <> "" Then ' some times, even if this if is true, it steps to the next loopvar2
                shtOutput1.Cells(loopvar1, targetColumn + 1) = matchArray(loopvar2, matchColumn + 1)
                shtOutput1.Cells(loopvar1, 1) = cleanoutputArray(loopvar1, 1)
                shtOutput1.Cells(loopvar1, 2) = cleanoutputArray(loopvar1, 2)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next loopvar2
    Next loopvar1

End function
```

**Question:** What could be causing this error?

Comment: Did you ever try in a worksheet: `=A1=A2` for the cells that you think should be matching? Usually there is a trailing or leading space that throws this comparison off.

Comment: Yes, @Luuklag has a point. Try adding a `Trim` to your reading of the cells.

Comment: @LuuklagI tried that, it yielded a false. I copied both and pasted into the text editor, they are identical.

Comment: In your testing, does it 'skip' the same entries every time? If so, work out what the values of `loopvar1` and `loopvar2` are at that point and insert a conditional `Stop` inside your loop so flow breaks on that cell combination. Then you can use the Watch window and Step-through to examine exactly what is happening.

Comment: what is `ratingsColumn`?

Comment: @tom, my mistake, it should be matchcolumn

Comment: @DGMS89 Do you still have the same issue?

Comment: @CLR I did exactly that, steping line by line.It always break on the same one but in the code, the two cells appear identical.

Comment: @Tom Yes. The error was just when I transferred the question to SO.

Comment: How do you call the `Function`? and why are you using a `Function` and not a `Sub` as you don't return any value?

Comment: @DGMS89, pasting into text editor? That sounds like you're visually comparing them. Might be better to turn into an array of `bytes` or an array of code points. Some characters are visually similar (to humans), but have different character code points. You can create a helper  function (purely for debugging) which will do this for you (return the position/index of the first byte/character that differs).

Comment: @Tom Initially this function returned a variable. I changed it to write directly to a worksheet, but did not change it to a Sub (will do that for the next steps, thanks for reminding me)

Comment: @chillin Thanks for the tip, I will try that.

Comment: @DGMS89 if that yields a false, values are simply not the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is not the fix to your problem. However, it is a little tool that might help you with your issue:

```
Function stringcompare(strA As String, strB As String)
    If StrComp(strA, strB, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then stringcompare = "Text match (case insensitive)"
    If StrComp(strA, strB) = 0 Then stringcompare = "Perfect match"
    If Len(strA) <> Len(strB) Then stringcompare = "Length of strings not matching"
    If StrComp(Trim(strA), Trim(strB), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then stringcompare = "Text match (case insensitive) but with padding"
    If StrComp(Trim(strA), Trim(strB)) = 0 Then stringcompare = "Perfect match but with padding"
    If stringcompare <> "" Then Exit Function
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To Len(strA)
        stringcompare = stringcompare & "('" & Mid(strA, i, 1) & IIf(Mid(strA, i, 1) = Mid(strB, i, 1), "'='", "'<>'") & Mid(strB, i, 1) & "') "
    Next
End Function
```

**Using this in the right place *at the right time* will allow you to see what is causing the two strings to mismatch.**

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of errors in your code which would no doubt cause this issue:

- ratingsColumn is not referenced in the function header (probably your issue)
- shtOutput1 is not referenced in the scope of the function (it might be a global variable though)

Another issue could potentially be non-printing characters within the values

> The following is untested but should work. It also currently directly replaces the values within the InArray which may not work with your other code without tweaking...

```
Function InnerReplace(ByRef InArray As Variant, ByVal MatchArray As Variant, TargetCol As Long, MatchCol As Long, ReplaceCol As Long)
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, Str1 As String, Str2 As String
    For i = 2 To UBound(InArray, 1)
        Str1 = CleanStr(CStr(InArray(i, TargetCol + 1)))
        For j = 2 To UBound(MatchArray, 1)
            Str2 = CleanStr(CStr(MatchArray(j, MatchCol)))
            If Str1 = Str2 And Str1 <> "" Then
                InArray(i, TargetCol + 1) = MatchArray(j, ReplaceCol) 'Str2
'                shtOutput1.Cells(i, TargetCol + 1) = MatchArray(j, MatchCol + 1)
'                shtOutput1.Cells(i, 1) = InArray(i, 1)
'                shtOutput1.Cells(i, 2) = InArray(i, 2)
'                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

End Function

Function CleanStr(ByVal Value As String, Optional Clean As String = False) As String
    Dim i As Long, NonPrint() As Variant: NonPrint = Array(127, 129, 141, 143, 144, 157)
    For i = LBound(NonPrint) To UBound(NonPrint)
        CleanStr = Replace(CleanStr, Chr(NonPrint(i)), "")      ' Replace non-printing characters
    Next i
    CleanStr = Replace(CleanStr, Chr(160), Chr(32))             ' Replace strange space character

    If Clean = True Then CleanStr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(CleanStr)
End Function
```